React Native Gradle Error: unable to resolve class com.andorid.build.OutputFile
I'm working on a large React Native project with React 18.2.0, React Native 0.74.0, and Gradle 7.3. However, when I try to build the application, I encounter errors both in the terminal and in Visual Studio Code's Problems tab. Based on my research, this issue seems to be due to an incompatibility between the Gradle and AGP versions, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip


buildscript {
    ext {
        //This for rndevice info library
        googlePlayServicesIidVersion = "16.0.1"

        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.3"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
    }

Terminal Output:
PS C:\ReactNativeProjects\kaptankosku> npx react-native run-android
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\ReactNativeProjects\kaptankosku\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 397        
> Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@1c644dce] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory_Decorated.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 5s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Running '[node, -e, try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e) {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}]' command failed. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Script 'C:\ReactNativeProjects\kaptankosku\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 397 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script. > Could not find method exec() for arguments [ReactNativeModules$_getCommandOutput_closure16@1c644dce] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory_Decorated. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BU�LD FAILED in 5s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

package.json:
"dependencies": {
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "2.0.0",
        "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.14.3",
        "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.17",
        "@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro": "^12.3.6",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.2.0",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.4.1",
        "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^21.2.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^21.2.0",
        "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.6.1",
        "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.18",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "6.4.1",
        "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.4",
        "axios": "^1.7.7",
        "fbjs": "^3.0.5",
        "i18next": "23.16.4",
        "moment": "^2.30.1",
        "prop-types": "15.8.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "15.1.0",
        "react-native": "^0.74.0",
        "react-native-animatable": "1.4.0",
        "react-native-appearance": "^0.0.0",
        "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.11",
        "react-native-calendars": "1.1307.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "^14.0.0",
        "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.11",
        "react-native-fast-image": "8.6.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.20.2",
        "react-native-get-location": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^7.1.2",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-maps": "1.18.2",
        "react-native-modal": "13.0.1",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^18.0.0",
        "react-native-pager-view": "6.4.1",
        "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.5",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
        "react-native-quick-md5": "^3.0.6",
        "react-native-reanimated": "3.16.1",
        "react-native-restart": "0.0.27",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.35.0",
        "react-native-share": "^11.0.4",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "3.3.0",
        "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
        "react-native-tab-view": "3.5.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "10.2.0",
        "react-native-webview": "^13.12.3",
        "react-redux": "9.1.2",
        "redux": "5.0.1",
        "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
        "redux-thunk": "3.1.0",
        "rn-range-slider": "2.2.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.9",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.26.0",
        "@babel/traverse": "^7.25.9",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.11.0",
        "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-plugin-ft-flow": "^3.0.11",
        "eslint-plugin-jest": "^28.8.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^4.1.0",
        "glob": "^11.0.0",
        "jest": "^29.7.0",
        "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "react-native-codegen": "^0.70.7",
        "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^6.0.1"
    }

I tried performing a Gradle sync in Android Studio but didn’t get any results.
